# How to sign in with Google on tvOS

Tags: google-oauth, tvos

Given that there is no Safari or Webkit on tvOS is there a good way to sign in with google using this https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/devices or some other path?

I suppose one has to leverage iOS/iPadOS or MacOS device and transfer the token to tvOS somehow?